# wkbMultiPoint to wkbPoint conversion using python

Tags: python, pyqgis, gdal

Is there a way to convert an ogr.wkbMultiPoint geometry (only one record for several points in the attribute table) to an ogr.wkbPoint one (a record per point) using python or pyQgis?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Do you want an OGR API solution or PyQGIS? They will look very different.

Comment: Hi ndawson. I would prefer a pyqgis one. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your description "only one record for several points in the attribute table". Multipoint has many points as elementary geometries but only one set of attributes. If you explode a multipoint then you will get many points which all have exactly same attributes.

Comment: Yes. Actually my vector is made by 50 points, but you can see only one line in the attribute table. I would like to explode the multipoint obtaining 50 points and 50 lines with a progressive id number